# Set Cell Background Color from index path corresponding Color in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uitableview

I have a `Table View`, and I want to **color the background of the `cell`s based on the corresponding color I have stored in `Parse`**.

*I can't figure out how to grab the color from the `array`s corresponding cell and make it the background color of the cell.*

Any ideas? Will post any extra code as necessary, thanks!

**This is what I have for the table with no background color:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    homeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"matchup"];

    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    dateLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"time"];

    return cell;
}
```

**This is what I have for the array of colors for the query results of the query I made to `Parse`:**

[image]

**Here is the array variable that I already have holding the colors from my `Parse` query:**

```
// Color Cell
NSLog(@"Color array global: %@", self.stringArrayColor);

// Output in console
2015-02-19 19:07:52.964 SimpleTable[12628:1448286] Color array global: (
    006532,
    061642
)
```

**Here is a method I have to convert the Hex String colors:**

```
// Added to convert Hex colors to RGB
-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];
    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];
    // MATT ADDED THIS SO IF COLOR RETURNED NULL, THEN THE COLOR WOULD BE SET TO ICON COLOR NAVY BLUE, SAME AS TINT COLOR
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"("]) return [UIColor colorWithRed:7.0f/255.0f green:32.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];
    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];
    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

**Here's an example of the type of way I've used that `method` before, just to give you an idea, if it helps:**

```
[buttonOne setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theColor]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your own example you provided:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:[self.stringArrayColor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```